# redirect output console message of bash command

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, suppressmessage

I execute following command

```
bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort vms1.txt) <(sort vms2.txt)'
```

and it gives following output

```
sort: cannot read: vms1.txt: No such file or directory
sort: cannot read: vms2.txt: No such file or directory
```

how to suppress the above message? I tried stderr redirection method but didn't work

```
bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort vms1.txt) <(sort vms2.txt) 2>&-'
```

The point is to suppress error message and don't want to show on stdout.

Comment: `bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort vms1.txt 2>/dev/null) <(sort vms2.txt 2>/dev/null)'`

Comment: thanks @Abelisto 
It did help